# How can I make my eth0 connection default on startup?

Tags: networking, ubuntu-9.10, kubuntu, networkmanager

I'm running kubuntu 9.10 and every time I log in auto eth0 is used instead of my custom connection called "batnet".  I have batnet set to automatically connect, but despite this it is ignored and the default auto eth0 is used instead.  This would be fine IF I could somehow figure out how to define a static ip for auto eth0.  I would prefer to just make the 'batnet' connection default.  How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For static assignment on Debian-based systems, you need to edit `/etc/network/interfaces`.

example:

```
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

auto eth0
iface eth0 inet static
        address 208.88.34.106
        netmask 255.255.255.248
        broadcast 208.88.34.111
        network 208.88.34.104
        gateway 208.88.34.110
```

to change it back to DHCP:

```
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

auto eth0
iface eth0 inet dhcp
```

Answer (score 0):

You could put a script in /etc/init.d/ to run on startup that would turn off eth0;

```
sudo ifconfig eth0 down
```